# Matching enum with combo box list doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, enums

[UPDATE: Added `Form1()` constructor]

I am trying to match some data from certain clases into combo box values in windows form application.

What I've done until now looks like this:

(This class has some `region[]` values that I want to store in a combobox, depending on `enum Project`)

```
public Form1()
{
    formatWorker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    formatWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;

    extractWorker.DoWork += extractWorker_DoWork;
    extractWorker.ProgressChanged += extractWorker_ProgressChanged;
    extractWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += extractWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;

    InitializeComponent();
    projectBox.DataSource = Constant.projects.ToString(); 
    projectBox.SelectedIndex = (int)Regions.Project.NBTevo;
    PopulateUsbDevices();
}

class Regions
{
    public enum Project
    {
        NBT = 0,
        NBTevo = 1,
        MGU = 2
    }

    string[] regions = { "ARG", "AUSNZ", "ECE", "IND", "ISR", "LA", "ME", "NA", "NAF", "NANT", "PAL", "SEA", "TC", "ZA" };

    public string[] GetRegionsForProject(Project proj)
    {
        //all directories from /Databases/proj[i]
        string[] allDirectories = Constant.ExtractFileNames(Directory.GetDirectories(Constant.path + "//" + Constant.projects[(int)proj]));


        string[] availableSubDirectories = Enumerable.Intersect(allDirectories, regions).ToArray();

        return availableSubDirectories;
    }
}
```

The next class stores a certain pattern files

```
class DBVersion
{        
    public string[] GetVersion(string proj, string region)
    {
        string pattern = "^" + proj + "_" + region + "_" + @"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\.iso$";
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Constant.path + "\\" + proj + "\\" + region + "\\images\\", "*.iso", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        return files;

    }
}
```

I am trying to build a dependency, for example, depending on the selected values in `projectBox` and `regionBox` some versions will appear in `versionBox`

```
private void projectBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isoPaths.Clear();
    populateRegions((Regions.Project)Enum.Parse(typeof(Regions.Project), projectBox.SelectedValue.ToString()));
    regionBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    regionBox_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
}

private void regionBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] versionPaths = version.GetVersion(projectBox.SelectedValue.ToString(), regionBox.SelectedItem.ToString());

    isoPaths.Clear();
    isoPaths.AddRange(versionPaths);

    populateVersions(Constant.ExtractFileNames(versionPaths));
    //versionBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    //versionBox_SelectedIndexChanged(null, null);
}

private void versionBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
private void populateRegions(Regions.Project proj) 
{ 

    this.regionBox.DataSource = region.GetRegionsForProject(proj); 
} 

private void populateVersions(string[] versions) 
{ 
    this.versionBox.DataSource = version.GetVersion(
                    projectBox.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                    region‌​Box.SelectedItem.ToS‌​tring()); 
}
```

After running, I don't have nothing stored in `ComboBox`

Comment: I don't see any code where you populate your comboboxes or bind the `DataSource` of it. May be my eyes are just too tired.

Comment: You are right. This is the thing that i don't know how to do, sorry for being unclear

Comment: I have two methods:
`private void populateRegions(Regions.Project proj)
        {
            this.regionBox.DataSource = region.GetRegionsForProject(proj);
        } 
private void populateVersions(string[] versions)
        {
            this.versionBox.DataSource = version.GetVersion(projectBox.SelectedItem.ToString(),regionBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
` but i can't seem to put them together

Comment: if you bind them as datasource it should actually work, you need to check in the debugger what the methods return. It seems that the `string[]` are empty. Otherwise you should see something in the `ComboBox`es. Have you tried to bind `this.versionBox.DataSource = versionPaths` in the `regionBox_SelectedIndexChanged` event. What value does `GetVersion` and `Constant.ExtractFileNames` return. Furthermore you don't use the parameter `versions` in the `populateVersions` method, why?

Comment: i know am still a nooby, but still doesn't work for me. can you please what should i do

Comment: it is difficult to help you. I need more information. I opened up a chat room. You can enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind a `DataSource` to a `ComboBox` you should use :

> An object that implements the IList interface or an Array

according to the [ComboBox.DataSource Property documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8160f6f(v=vs.110).aspx)

So this line in the constructor of `Form1`:

```
projectBox.DataSource = Constant.projects.ToString();
```

has to be changed into this:

```
projectBox.DataSource = Constant.projects;
```

The rest of the comboboxes is empty because the problem cascades from one to the next. If one is empty then the rest cannot be filled appropriately